# Add / show different divs' content according to a defined timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, hide, show

Good morning everybody.

I built a **grid WordPress template** that should work this way:

1. fade in div#1's content, show it for some time, fade out the content;
2. fade in div#2's content (a slider), start the slider, show all the slides, when it finishes its loop fade out the content;
3. fade in div#3's content, show it for some time, fade out the content;
4. fade in div#4's content, show it for some time, fade out the content;
5. start the loop back again from step 1.

I managed to achieve the result you can see [***here***](http://goo.gl/jHBo4Y), but **it's very difficult to match the correct timing** for each fade in / fade out, **and the slider's behaviour isn't what I need**.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<section id="home_first_box" class="sec_double first">
    <span>some content</span>
</section>
<section class="sec_single"></section>
<section id="home_box_3" class="sec_single last">
    <img>
</section>
<section id="home_box_4" class="sec_single first">
    <img>
</section>
<section class="sec_single"></section>
<section class="sec_single"></section>
<section id="home_box_7" class="sec_single last">
    <img>
</section>
<section class="sec_single first bottom slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">                                                     

                <li>
                    <img>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img>
                </li>                               
        </ul>
    </div>                                
</section>
<section class="sec_single bottom"></section>
<section id="home_second_box" class="sec_double last bottom">
    <span>some other content</span>
</section></div>
```

And here is the (awful) JavaScript / jQuery code I'm using:

```
function startSlider() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider( {
    animationLoop: true,
    controlNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 1000,
    animationSpeed: 500,
    after: function(slider)  {
        if ( slider.currentSlide == (slider.count - 1) <? // slides count starts from 0 ?> )  {
        slider.pause();
        setTimeout(function (){slider.play()},5000);
        }
    }
});
}


function HomeLooper() {
    $('#home_box_3 img').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500,startSlider);
    $('.flexslider').delay(1500).fadeIn(500).delay(4500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#home_box_4 img').delay(6000).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#home_box_7 img').delay(7000).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500,HomeLooper);
}
```

I don't include CSS code because it isn' relevant, I think.

**I'm looking for a different approach** to the problem, this one is too difficult to manage and has no flexibility at all.

Could anyone address me to a **better way** to achieve what I need? I don't need a working code (really appreciated anyway, but I want to have fun by myself!), just a tip to find a better way.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle?

Comment: Not yet, I'll create one asap

Comment: [**Here's the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XqkTz/12/), slider CSS isn't perfect but it doesn't matter I think.